# Reading src attribute to generate href

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-attributes

I am using a lightbox called nyromodal and I am calling it manually on some thumbnail images to open a larger image.

Code:

```
    onclickActiveItem: function (item) {
    $('img.active').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.nyroModalManual({
     url: 'image.jpg'
   });
   return false;
    });
```

I don't want to enter the url for each image ( as in "image.jpg") and would like a function to read the src and convert it to an href in the above code. I am thinking something like this but I am not able to find a way for it to work in the code I have.

```
  $('img.active').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var nyro = element.getAttribute('src');
 element.setAttribute('href', nyro);
    $.nyroModalManual({
     url: 'nyro'
   });
   return false;
    });
```

Currently it will just open the src image in a new page. I would appreciate any help !
I am a novice, so be gentle….

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you're setting the url incorrectly and the javascript is failing.

try

```
    $('.nyroclickable').click(function(e) {
       $.nyroModalManual({
           url: this.src;
       });
       return false;
    });
```

and apply the 'nyroclickable' class to your images

Comment: Thanks. Still opening a link in a new window but i will work on it. i appreciate the help!

Comment: This seems to work when I change src to href:$('.active').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.nyroModalManual({
   url: $(this).attr('href')
       });
       return false;
        });

Comment: I removed the e.preventDefault() as the return false; should take care of it. Apparently not. Good to hear you've fixed it. Its definately worth taking the time to look through jQuery's selectors & event bindings. They save a lot of hassle

Comment: `this.src`, please. Don't need to create new jQuery objects just to access a DOM element's attrbiutes

Comment: I've updated the code with your change Yi, thanks for pointing that out. Spent too long at the keyboard today

Comment: Interesting in when i change the code to "url: this.href", nylomodal scales the images downward. Not sure why except that for some reason this code must no allow the lightbox to expand beyond the default minimum size. Very weird!